# SqlDataReader and method scope

Tags: c#-4.0, sqldatareader

Why is data read from SqlDataReader not available to a method call?
I have a table, with 'id' as column in it.
When I make a query to database, it returns rows.

This code doesnt work (Says 'id' column doesnt exist):

```
con.Open();
SqlDataReader requestReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (requestReader.HasRows)
{
   DataTable requestTable = requestReader.GetSchemaTable();
   request = ReadRequest(requestTable.Rows[0]);        
}

con.Close();
```

while this one works:

```
con.Open();
SqlDataReader requestReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (requestReader.HasRows)
{
   DataTable requestTable = requestReader.GetSchemaTable();
   var requestRow = requestTable.Rows[0];
   request = new Request();
   request.UniqueId = (string)requestRow["id"];
}

con.Close();
```

Comment: And what is the code of that  ReadRequest that doesn't work?

Comment: stupid question. Like Tim said, even the second approach didnt work, but due to quick testing and code-structuring, I didnt catch that. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`DataReader.GetSchemaTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns a `DataTable` with all schema informations for a given table.

It has following columns:

```
ColumnName
ColumnOrdinal
ColumnSize
NumericPrecision
// .. 26 others
```

So you don't find your id-column which belongs to your table. That's why you get the error "'id' column doesnt exist". I doubt that your second approach works. I don't see why you need `GetSchemaTable` at all. You just have to advance the reader to the next record:

```
if (requestReader.HasRows && requestReader.Read())
{
   int id = requestReader.GetInt32(requestReader.GetOrdinal("id"));
   // ...
}
```